# How to get a resource(folder) from a jar?

Tags: java, jar, resources, directory

Basically what i'm trying to do is parse through all the files of a directory and add all the childen to a List< File> .
The catch is that I don't have a main function, I'm running just a jar. So I can't do this:

```
URL url = MyClass.class.getResource("resources/");
if (url == null) {
     // error - missing folder
} else {
    File dir = new File(url.toURI()); //throws error when running the jar
    for (File nextFile : dir.listFiles()) {
        // Do something with nextFile
    }
}
```

as it throws IllegalArgument Exception. I've also tried getting an InputStream with:

```
InputStream inStream = CompilerUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath)
```

But it seems it's not working for files. I'm looking for an alternative of this that works for directories.

Answer (score 0):

Get string represenataion of url `url.getFile()` it will look like `file:/C:/xxx/yyy/x.jar!/resources` extract path from it: `C:/xxx/yyy/x.jar.` Use JarFile class to read folders